# How to disable UICollectionViewCell when UICollectionview is scrolling in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I want to disable UICollectionViewCell Selection when UICollectionView is scrolling. The problem is, I'm trying to set `cell.isSelected` in `didSelectItemAt` , but as I've written cell behavior of selection and deselection it's not working.

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {

        if isSelected {
          //selection Code 
        else{
         //deselection Code
        }
}
```

UPDATE: I want to stop selection while scrolling beacause, consider event when I tap on cell but didn't released my tap. Instead I scroll and released. In this scenario what collectionView doing is, it first call didSelect(I've written code which performs deselection if cell is already selected). So in this case collectionView performs deselection till my tap is ongoing on cell, causing to deselection of cell, but when I scroll and release the tap from collectionView it selects the cell again as it knew the event was actually "scroll" but not the "tap".

Comment: how will you do 2 in 1 one thing? selection while scrolling itself sounds wrong.Either stop scrolling and select , or just scroll.

Comment: @TusharSharma thanks for replying, please go through my question again as I've updated it. And please let me know if it elaborates enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting `isSelected` in `didSelect()` method,

`didSelect()` method is called only when you have selected a collectionViewCell item, in case you have to work with deselection then you can write that code in `didDeselect()`